# Does a sequence that iterates a convex function have a limit (under some extra assumptions)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-analysis

Consider a function $f(x): \mathbb{R_{+}} \to \mathbb{R_{+}}$ such that $f'(x)>0$, $f''(x)<0$, $f''(x)$ is continuous, $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0)>1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) < 1$. Let $T_n$ be a sequence defined as $T_0 = x_0 > 0$ and $T_{n+1}=f(T_{n})$. Show that $T$ has a limit.

My proof is as follows. By the Intermediate Value Theorem and the fact that $f''(x)<0$, there exists $x'$ such that $f'(x') = 1$, $\forall x < x': f'(x)>1$ and $\forall x > x': f'(x) < 1$. Suppose first that $x_0$ is such that $\forall n: T_n \leq x'$. Because $T_n >0$ and $\forall x < x'$, $f$ is monotonically increasing, the result follows from the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Suppose instead that there exists $N$ such that $T_N > x'$. Then let $q \equiv f'(T_n)$ and observe that $\forall x \geq T_N: f'(x) \leq q$. Fix some $x,y \geq T_n, x < y$ and notice that $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y - x}=f'(z)$ for some $z \in [x,y]$ and therefore $0 < \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y - x} \leq q < 1 \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(x)|\leq q |y-x|$. Hence, the sequence ${T_N,T_{N+1},...,}\$ satisfies the conditions of Banach's fixed-point therem, and therefore has a limit.

My specific questions are: 1. Is this a correct argument? 2. Is there a way to prove this more elegantly? 3. If the argument is wrong, can a version of this result with some extra assumptions be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just a small note: your function is concave, not convex.

Your argument has a hole in the second case. You assume explicitly that $T_N > x'$ for some $N$, but seem to implicitly assume that once $T_N > x'$, then every subsequent $T_n$ is also greater than $x'$. This happens to be true, but your argument doesn't really address this. I think the main reason for this is that you've chosen your $x'$ poorly; choosing a different point will yield neater results.

You should choose $x'$ to be the non-zero fixed point of $f$. Let's start by proving such a point exists, and is unique.

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$. Then, $g'(0) > 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} g'(x) < 0$, and $g'$ is strictly decreasing. Note that $g'(0) > 0$ implies there exists a small $y_1 > 0$ such that $g(y_1) > 0$. Also, $\lim_{x \to \infty} g'(x) < 0$ implies that there exist some $m$ and $b$ such that $0 > m > \lim g'(0)$ and $g(x) < mx + b$ holds for sufficiently large $x$. In particular, this implies $g(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, and so there exists some large $y_2$ such that $g(y_2) < 0$. As $g$ is differentiable, the intermediate value theorem shows that some $y'$ exists between $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $g(y') = y'$.

We can also show $y'$ is unique using Rolle's theorem: between any two roots of $g$, there must be a stationary point, but since $f'$ is strictly decreasing, at most one such stationary point exists. Given $g(0) = g(y') = 0$, we have at least one stationary point, and exactly two roots, only one of which is strictly positive.

Thus, a unique positive root $y'$ of $g$ exists, which is a unique positive fixed point of $f$. This is the point that we should be using instead of $x'$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, any $T_N < y'$ will also have $T_{N+1} = f(T_N) < f(y') < y'$, i.e. the iterates will remain to the left of $y'$. A similar argument shows that $T_n > y' \implies T_{N+1} > y'$. So, the entire sequence lies to the left or to the right of $y'$.

Coming back to $g$, since $g$ is continuous and has a unique positive root $y'$, and $y_0 < y'$ exists such that $g(y_0) > 0$, we must have $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, y')$. Further, similarly given $g(y_1) < 0$ and $y_1 > y'$, we have $g(x) < 0$ for $x \in (y', \infty)$.

This implies that, when $T_n < y'$, we have
$$0 < g(T_n) = f(T_n) - T_n = T_{n+1} - T_n \implies T_{n+1} > T_n.$$
Similarly, if $T_n > y'$, then $T_{n+1} < T_n$, as $g(T_n) < 0$. So, when the sequence lies to the left of $y'$, it increases, and when it lies to the right, it decreases. Thus, using monotone convergence theorem in both cases, $T_n$ converges. Also, if $T_n = y'$, then $T_n$ is constantly $y'$, which implies convergence in all cases.

---

Your argument in the second case still does work, though it is missing steps. Note that $x' < y'$, by the MVT applied to $[0, y']$. So, if $T_N > x'$, then either $T_n < y'$ or $T_N \ge y'$. In the first case, $T_{N+1} > T_N > x'$. In the second case, $T_{N+1} \ge y' > x'$. In either case, the iterates will remain to the right of $x'$, and your argument shows that the Banach fixed point theorem does apply to this tail end of the sequence, and a limit must exist.

I cannot think of a way to correct your argument without finding and referring to the unique fixed point of $f$.

Comment: I like your argument more. Do you know if it's some well-known result?

Comment: @ArseniySamsonov It's certainly known; specific examples of this kind of theorem are used all the time as exercises for more advanced first year mathematics students, or second years learning proofs. But, I don't know a general, named theorem that covers this. I also feel like it's very possible that there is a named theorem that I'm just not aware of that will cover this.